# Why is the data column empty? Laravel Notifications

Tags: laravel, notifications

I am trying to set up database notification, but the data I am sending for the 'data' column isn't showing up...

My notification class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use App\User;
use App\Admin;

class UserAddedToStudio extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    public $user;
    public $admin;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, Admin $admin)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->admin = $admin;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail', 'database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject('Welcome to '.$this->admin->name.'\'s studio')
                    ->line('Hi '.$this->user->name.'. Your request to join '.$this->admin->name.'\'s studio has been accepted! Now you can start registering for lessons.')
                    // ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'message' => 'You have been added to the studio'

        ];
    }
}
```

In my notifications table on MySQL all the columns are filled except for the `data` column. There I only get an empty array `[]`. but why?? so frustrating.... :(

Here is the screenshot from my phpmyadmin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `toArray()` instead of `toDatabase()`

```
/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'message' => 'You have been added to the studio'

    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you use Queue you should restart the queue worker.

```
php artisan queue: work
```

> Remember, queue workers, are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory. As a result, they will not notice changes in your code base after they have been started. So, during your deployment process, be sure to restart your queue workers. In addition, remember that any static state created or modified by your application will not be automatically reset between jobs.